# Is there a way to automate Powerbi-Service Dataset

Tags: powerbi, refresh, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I currently develop reports on Power BI desktop and publish to Service. The data is a spreadsheet resident on ONEDRIVE for Business. I found out that when i update the spreadsheet and refresh the desktop report it updates but the published report on service doesn't. Meaning i have to republish everytime i send out the report.

I get the error below when i try to refresh the dataset to the report manually:

Data source error: Scheduled refresh is disabled because at least one data source is missing credentials. To start the refresh again, go to this dataset's settings page and enter credentials for all data sources. Then reactivate scheduled refresh.
Cluster URI: WABI-NORTH-EUROPE-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: 7b3dfb3e-9982-4f44-bc8a-23fe4c766b4b
Request ID: 9d492aae-db23-3ae1-4568-de6e7b071f5d
Time: 2021-07-06 07:43:39Z

Answer (score 1):

Goto your workspace, find a dataset. Click [...] -> settings -> here we have Gateway connection  and Data source credentials -> check this place.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem